# Turning the logging off in Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft

I have a requirement as I need to turn the logging off in the Mulesoft Flow. I need to to this at logger level and if possible at Http connector level as well. Tried changing the INFO as OFF in log4j2.xml file but no luck. What parameters in log4j2.xml file I need to update to make it work.Right now I have done it for asynchronous logger.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you read this ? https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/94058/turn-off-logging-for-an-onprem-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do that. I strongly advise against disabling logging. Logging is the number one tool to troubleshoot issues you have. To reduce logging it is preferable to set it to a higher level, like WARN or ERROR. I can't think an scenario that requires it. If you **absolutely** need to turn it off, and understand clearly the tradeoffs, you need to set each package (or category) to a higher level, like WARN, ERROR or OFF. The top level packages for Mule and MuleSoft are a good start.

Example:

```
<!-- DON'T DO THIS! -->   
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="ERROR"/>
<AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="ERROR"/>
```

You might still find log entries from some packages from third party libraries. You can iteratively add the levels for those too until nothing else is logged.

Note that if you have any issues you will be on your own with no clues as what happened.